# Firefox loading the window.opener address in the child instead of the parent

Tags: javascript, firefox, window.opener

I have an uploader which opens in a separate window from a file manager.
After the upload completes the page reloads and the upload was a success the server returns the html

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        window.opener.location.reload(); 
        self.close;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is intended to refresh the file manager. It works in IE 8 and 9, but in Firefox the child appears to load the parent window's address instead of the parent reloading.

Comment: That's... very odd.  Can you link to the page showing the problem?

Comment: @Boris Zbarsky, sorry I can't. It's a part of our administration side behind a login.

Comment: Could you provide us the real piece of code please?